# how to refer to instances of clickonce app running on different machines?

Tags: clickonce

I'm creating a WPF application that will run on 20 PC's simultaneously.
My app contains an ID field, that will fetch the ID value from database 
and I want each running instance of the app to fetch different value.
Something like :
on 1st PC..ID should be 001, on 2nd PC..should be 002..& so on...so, my question is is
it possible to refer to an instance of clickonce app to do this..any help will be appreciated...thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve? Don't even bring ClickOnce into it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: problem is- I just want to set a unique ID for each instance of my clickonce app that is going to run on 20 PCs simultaneously via C#...

Comment: When your app starts, call a service method and pass the MAC address. If the server has never seen that MAC before, assign them a new ID, store it, and send it back. If the server has seen the MAC before, look up their ID and send it back. I understand you want a unique ID assigned, but can you explain why? What problem does this ID solve?

Comment: actually I'm trying to create an online examination system, so..I just want each instance of my clickonce app to have the student ID that is permitted by the examiner to appear for the examination...that's what I'm trying to accomplish...well I'll go with your suggestion, can you refer any link that will guide me how to accomplish the solution that you've suggested..^here???